# Preconditioned Steepest Descent

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-analysis

For my program assignment I need to write a preconditioned steepest descent algorithm. I have psedo-code from my professor which is here:[image: PSD]

From reading in my text on this method they say that $P$ is the preconditioned matrix but they do not define it in any way shape or form. I am not sure at all, but by my professors psedo-code I would guess that $M$ is $P$? I honestly have no idea if that is the case. I have tried to search online for this but I seem to be getting information that is not very consistent with the way our book/professor presents the material.

Update: $M$ is just a general precondition matrix; i.e. Jabobi, or any other precondition matrix. The problem I seem to be having now is that I do not really understand the pseudo-code. I have all the ingredients necessary to start but I am not sure how to begin.

Note: the book I am using is,  A. Quarteroni, R. Sacco, and F. Saleri, Numerical Mathematics,

Comment: What happens if you insert $M:=A$? This choice would be expensive since solving $Az_0 = r_0$ would be expensive. Therefore, one chooses an approximation $M$ for $A$ for which the system can  be solved much easier. This implies an approximative solution. Therefore, the recursive reduction of the residuum.

Comment: This may be a case of needing to ask your professor for more information. There are multiple simple choices for a preconditioner (Jacobi, incomplete LU, SOR) and it's also possible to apply the preconditioner from the left rather than the right, q.v. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Preconditioning_for_linear_systems

Comment: The first line just states the assumptions. You do not need to code these. The second line is the first thing you need to code: 1st: Choose an arbitrary first estimation $x_0$ of the solution. If you do not have any glue of the solution use the zero-vector for $x_0$. 2nd: Calculate the first residual $r_0=b-Ax_0$ and solve the preconditioning system $Mz_0 = r_0$. All successive lines are further things you have to code.

Comment: I have $x_0$ and I have $r_0 = b - Ax_0$ I assume $b$ is arbitrary. Note: I am using arrays for all this and I had to store the matrices $A$ and $M$ in efficient ways so that I save storage cost which was quite tricky but with a lot of devoted time I was able to do it. I just don't understand the $Mz_0 = r_0$ part. I am just confused how I code that. Would it be helpful to post my code?

Comment: @Tobias any chance you could help me with this part? I can post my code, I think it is pretty easy to read for the most part

Comment: You need to solve $Mz_0=r_0$ via some of the designated methods for solving linear systems. [Cholesky's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) method is suitable for symmetric positive definite systems. You do not need pivoting. This makes the method very nicely applicable to banded systems.

Comment: @Tobias ok, I see but can we use arrays to solve $Mz_0 = r_0$?

Comment: The algorithm is what matters. Programming details such as storage scheme are secondary. Everything is possible. That said, yes it is possible to use arrays to solve linear systems. But, maybe you have to iterate element-wise/row-wise/column-wise over an array.

Comment: @Tobias ok, thank you. I will try to do that. Also, would it be useful to post my code so that I can get an answer on helping me code $Mz_0 = r_0$?